# Why didn't Robby send someone else to get the court documents?

Tags: plot-explanation, spotlight

In the film, Michael learns from Garabedian that several "damning" documents he needs were made publicly available, but that Michael won't be able to get them because the Church has likely already removed them from the archives, which turns out to be true. So, a legal process is used to "force" Garabedian to resubmit the documents.

However, when the order to resubmit comes through, Michael is in Florida and thus can't be there as soon as they're made available again, raising the concern that the Church will act quickly to remove them. Michael's boss, Robby, tells him to get the earliest flight back to Boston that he can to retrieve them.

My question is: if the documents were that important to their story, and the  risk was high that they may be removed again, **why didn't Robby send someone else or even go himself to retrieve them?** It's made clear that they're allowed to make copies of the documents, so all someone would have to do is ask for them, make copies, and then Michael could review them upon his return. It didn't seem like Michael was needed to be present himself to obtain this information, and that someone, *anyone*, simply needed to obtain it.

Comment: Could be necessary that the person who requested the document, must be there to retrieve...

Comment: @Vishwa Could be, and if it is and there's proper proof of that, it would make a great answer. :D